# Escaping a WPDB Object in One Shot

Tags: wpdb, security, escaping

I know array mapping works for escaping a bunch of values in an array, making them safe for output in HTML.  But is there a way to do the same thing with an object?  If not, I guess the object could be converted to an array, escaped using htmlspecialchars via array mapping, then converted back to an object.  But maybe there's a more efficient way?

I'm talking specifically about an object created with $object = $wpdb->get_results($sql)

Comment: If I remember correctly, best practice is escaping on output (output as when the data leaves your application). As the moment of get results, the data is still within your application. I'm not sure of getting your point. (because in your question your are not asking about escaping `$sql`, right?)

Comment: Nope.  Let me re-phrase it and make it more basic of a question:  If I have multiple values in the results from the object in my original question, do I have to do something like this: echo '<div>'.htmlspecialchars($object->value1).'</div><div>'.htmlspecialchars($objectj->value2).'</div>'... etc. etc?  Or is there a way to escape the entire object in one shot?  Maybe similar to the way you can escape an array in one shot using array mapping.

Comment: That is exactly what I said: escape on output, in your case "escape on `echo`". There are several methods to do what you are asking for, for sure, but in your use case I don't see any advantage of doing that. If you are looking for perfomance, I think that any method to do that would be something like "loop over the object for escaping, then loop again for echoing". See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/#escaping-securing-output

Comment: I gotcha.  With so many functions for doing about anything, it would be nice if there was a function for retrieving data from the DB (like get_results, but maybe esc_results) where your values could be pre-escaped so you didn't have to use esc_html on everything after.  Guess I could write one somewhat simply.